# Buscar los componentes comunes de una lista

Tags: haskell

Estoy intentando hacer una función que me devuelva los componentes comunes de una lista de enteros. El código que tengo ahora mismo es el siguiente:

```
commonPrefix :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
commonPrefix xs ys = 
  case xs of
    [] -> []
    x:xs' -> 
      case ys of
      [] -> []
      y:ys' ->
        if x /= y
          then commonPrefix xs' ys'
          else (x:xs)
```

El problema es que esto no me devuelve los resultados que quiero. 
Donde se encuentra el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No dices qué resultado esperas y qué es lo que obtienes. Pero se puede intuir lo que pasa.

Si se analiza un poco la definición de `commonPrefix` se ve que, después de los *cases* y recursividad, devuelve una de dos: o una lista vacía `[]` o `(x:xs)` sea lo que sea esto.

En recursividad, necesitas algún modo de añadir elementos al resultado. De lo contrario, la cadena de llamadas acabará con el último elemento devuelto (en este caso, una lista vacía).

Así mismo, no es bueno que uses `case` e `if..then` si se pueden evitar. En haskell es buena práctica poner todos los casos posibles de llamada como "patrones" de llamadas, algo así:

```
commonPrefix :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
commonPrefix [] _ = []
commonPrefix _ [] = []
commonPrefix (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y    = x : commonPrefix xs ys
                           | otherwise = []
```

No estoy seguro si era esto lo que buscabas. Como he dicho al principio, falta saber cuál era el resultado que esperabas. Por el nombre, intuyo que quieres obtener los elementos comunes del principio de las dos listas.

Las dos primeras definiciones son los casos en lo que una de las dos listas de entrada está vacía. En la tercera, se compara el primer elemento de la dos listas y se sigue la recursión con el resto de lista.